# Rails Dysfunctional, requiring rack 1.3.5, have 1.4.0 but can't install 1.3.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, installation, rack

```
$ rails

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:777:in `report_activate_error': RubyGem version error: rack(1.4.0 not ~> 1.3.5) (Gem::LoadError)
            from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:211:in `activate'
            from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:246:in `activate'
            from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:245:in `each'
            from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:245:in `activate'
            from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:246:in `activate'
            from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:245:in `each'
            from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:245:in `activate'
            from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1056:in `gem'
            from /usr/bin/rails:18
```

Then I try this:

$ sudo gem install rack 1.3.5

Password:

Successfully installed rack-1.4.0

ERROR:  could not find gem 1.3.5 locally or in a repository

1 gem installed

Installing ri documentation for rack-1.4.0...

Cannot read termcap database;

using dumb terminal settings.

Installing RDoc documentation for rack-1.4.0...

then again but different:

```
rails
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:230:in `activate': can't activate rack (~> 1.3.5, runtime) for ["actionpack-3.1.3", "rails-3.1.3"], already activated rack-1.4.0 for ["rack-cache-1.1", "actionpack-3.1.3", "rails-3.1.3"] (Gem::LoadError)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:246:in `activate'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:245:in `each'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:245:in `activate'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:246:in `activate'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:245:in `each'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:245:in `activate'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1056:in `gem'
    from /usr/bin/rails:18
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to install rack 1.3.5 and remove rack 1.4.0

```
sudo gem install rack -v 1.3.5
sudo gem uninstall rack -v 1.4.0
```

Answer (score 1):

The command to install a specific version is

```
sudo gem install rack --version=1.3.5
```

What you've written is trying to find a gem called 1.3.5

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that didn't work either. Reinstalled everything but now am having path issues using heroku and git:

Comment: git push heroku master

 !  Invalid path.
 !  Syntax is: git@heroku.com:<app>.git where <app> is your app's name.

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Comment: That sounds completely unrelated to this question - something messed up with your git config

Comment: Thanks, .git/config had url = git@heroku.com:secendapp.git.git, I removed the second .git and eevrythings working now. Any idea how it got there?

Answer (score 0):

I'm believe its because of rack gem versions.

Give the command **gem list rack**

Its displays all the rack gems versions, after that I uninstalled all rack versions and run the bundle command hope you specified which version of rack you want in Gemfile.

I believe its because if you specify a rack version in Gemfile and if gems contrails a version greater than that, it my causes error.

So try to uninstall all the rack gems and run bundle command.

Hope it may help.